# Base level URL Landing pages issue

Tags: marketing-cloud, landing-page

We are working with a marketing partner who is using SalesForce. We set up a subdomain for this project which points at the SalesForce exacttarget.com domain.

We are currently running email and print campaigns that use several landing pages *subdomain.oursite.com/landingpage1, subdomain.oursite.com/landingpage2,* etc.

However, when someone goes to the base level URL (subdomain.oursite.com) they are met with a 403 error.

We have been trying to work our partner and SalesForce to find a solution to this but are being told that Marketing Cloud does not have the ability to serve up content at the base URL, nor can they forward it to an existing landing page.

Any ideas as to how we might fix this?

Comment: Did you choose to self-host the DNS for the new subdomain or did you delegate the subdomain to SFMC using NS records when setting up the Sender Authentication Package?

Comment: If you self-host the DNS it should be possible to accomplish a redirect. Otherwise Salesforce would need to adjust it and if they say they cannot or will not do it, your hands are tied.

Comment: @Macca The DNS for our domain is controlled by our primary development firm.  Salesforce sent a zone file for the subdomain which our firm implemented.

Comment: Well, you can't use something simple, like a CNAME record. I'd see if your primary development firm might be able to assist with implementing some sort of routing/query rewriting for the cloud. subdomain.